# Eclipse can't resolve <includes> despite seeing them in project's Includes

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have a C project opened in Eclipse that uses a third party library. I added a `/usr/local/include/` and `/usr/include/` to the project's includes and the Project explorer window shows all required header files correctly.

The build also works fine but the Editor part of the ide doesn't seem to be able to resolve `#include` pointing to the 3rd party header files correctly.

I've tried restarting Eclpse and rebuilding the index. I've also tried both default settings and `Enable project specific settings` for indexer, nothing work. Individual source files don't have specific configuration.

[image: Includes are visible in Project explorer]
[image: But they're not resolved in editor]

Answer (score 0):

Copying the header files to `~/devheaders` and pointing Eclipse there solved the issue, no idea why. Permissions on the header files were fine.